# Laravel 5 Eloquent: do not contain all fields after saving

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

for example there are 4 fields in table `users:`
    `name | avatar | created_at | updated_at`
when user model is saved with only `name:`

```
public function reg(){
  $user = new User; 
  $user->name = 'aName';    
  $user->save();
  return response()->json($user);
}
```

then I get the response json:

```
{
  "id":1;
  "name":"aName",
  "created_at":"xxxxxxxx",
  "updated_at":"xxxxxxxx"
}
```

there is no filed **avatar**, I want the response also contains **avatar** filed even I did not set value for it.

Comment: Is there an avatar column in your database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1) You need to execute one more query to get full record from database

```
$user = new User; 
$user->name = 'aName';    
$user->save();
return response()->json(User::find($user->id));
```

2) You can add in `AppServiceProvider` in `boot` method `creating` method for `User`

```
    User::creating(function ($user) {
        if ($user->avatar === null) {
            $user->avatar = null;
        }
    });
```

In both options you should finally get your `avatar` field but you need to decide what's better - one extra query to database or extra coding to fill in other fields with default values.

**EDIT**

Of course for line

```
$user->avatar = null;
```

you can set here any other value. For example

```
$user->avatar = 'default.jpg';
```

Comment: You can use **is_null($user->avatar)** to check is avatar null or not, instead of **$user->avatar === null**. That is a clean method